# LeakCanary not showing leaks in the app

Tags: android, leakcanary

I am using LeakCanary in my app and I have followed [this](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-it) guide to set it up in the app. LeakCanary shows leak notification in the app whenever there is a leak in the app and also I was able to find the **hprof** files in the phone storage which means it is collecting and dumping the leak data just fine. But the problem is that when I open the LeakCanary app titled *Leaks* on my device to get information on where exactly the leak happened, it shows an empty screen with no information on the leak that happened. Any idea why the app is not showing any data? I'm running my app on a device running Android 6.0.1 .

Comment: did you find a solution for that? I have the same problem on 1.5.x version.

Comment: Oh yes! Turns out it needed some time before it can process the hprof files and show us the leak data. So wait for a few minutes when the LeakCanary detects the leak and it will show the notification about the leak after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it takes a while untill the LeakCanary dumps the heap , give it some time